# JAXB is throwing an exception saying the property "retainReferenceToInfo" is invalid

Tags: java, jaxb

Mysteriously, JAXB is throwing a JAXBException that says that some property "retainReferenceToInfo" is invalid. No where in my code does this appear, what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this means that the version of Jersey and JAXB that I was using were incompatible - or more precisely transitive dependencies were pulling in an older version of JAXB. I removed this version of JAXB from the class path and everything seemed to work.